# Acceder a pagina según rol de usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una pagina de logon sobre una web, que haga que el usuario al acceder y según el rol o grupo al que pertenezca en la tabla mysql acceda a una página u otra.

Lo he intentado de varias maneras con un echo pero no ha funcionado. He mirado en foros y webs pero los intentos han sido infructuosos.

Agradecía que alguien me pueda echar una mano. ES UNA PÁGINA DE GESTION PERSONAL.

Pongo todo el código que he hecho:

```
<?php
$out ="";
 
if (isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {
    require ("pages/conn/connection.php");
        $uName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uName']);
        $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass1']);
        $grupo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grupo']);
 
        $salted ="*********************".$pass1."***********";
        $hashed = hash('sha512',$salted);
 
        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM login WHERE uName ='$uName' AND pass1 ='$hashed' AND grupo='$grupo'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("BAD SQL: $query");
 
 
 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            switch ($grupo){
 
                case "admin":
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                    header("location:pages/******/*****1.php"); 
                    require('pages/session/cookie.php');
                    break;
                case "renta":
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
                    header("location:pages/******/*****2.php"); 
                    require('pages/session/cookie.php');
                    break;
                default:
                    $out = "Fail to login. Check user or/and password";
 
            }
        }else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = '';
            $out = "Fail to login. Check user or/and password";
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener información de una fila de la BD con `mysqli_fetch_array`

```php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");
$uName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uName']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass1']);
$grupo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grupo']);
 
$salted ="*********************".$pass1."***********";
$hashed = hash('sha512',$salted);

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uName ='$uName' AND pass1 ='$hashed' AND grupo='$grupo'";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row["role"] == "admin") {
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
        header("location:pages/******/*****2.php", true, 301); 
    } elseif ($row["role"] == "renta") {
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
       header("location:pages/******/*****2.php", true, 301); 
    } else {
       die("Fail to login. Check user or/and password");
    }
}
```

Además hay cosas que no entiendo en tu código...

- ¿Para qué haces un redirect y después haces un `require`?
- ¿Por qué ese `1` y no un `*` en el query?

Otra cosa, estás iniciando la sesión en el `switch`, esto es incorrecto, necesitas iniciar la sesión al principio del archivo.

Comment: Hola anythingg,

Comment: SOLUCIONADO. He eliminado he descartado el campo grupo del codigo y la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Publico una respuesta para poder colgar el código.

El código publicado principal lo baje hace tiempo y que me ha funcionado siempre.

Sobre el código que me has pasado no me ha funcionado. El problema a la hora de colgar el código entero no me dejaba, por lo que eliminé toda la parte de html, de ahí `if (isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {` que indica si se ha pulsado el botón del formulario de logon.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {
        
        require ("pages/conn/connection.php");
        

$uName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uName']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass1']);
$grupo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grupo']);
 
$salted ="****".$pass1."****";
        $hashed = hash('sha512',$salted);

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uName ='$uName' AND pass1 ='$hashed' AND grupo='$grupo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("BAD SQL: $query");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    if ($row["grupo"] == "admin") {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
        header("location:***/***/****1.php", true, 301); 
    } elseif ($row["grupo"] == "renta") {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
       header("location:***/***/****2.php", true, 301); 
    } else {
        session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = '';
       die("Fail to login. Check user or/and password");
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="login" content="login">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


</head>
    <body>
<div  id="base">
    <div>
        <div >
        <picture>
            <!--<source media="(min-width: 602px) and (max-width: 800px)" srcset="../images/recibo-movil.png">
            <source media="(max-width: 480px)" srcset="images/recibo-movil.png">-->
            <img id="imagen" src="images/recibos.png" alt="Recibos">
        </picture>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Login de acceso</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <center>
            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
                <br><br><br>
                <div class="campo">
                    <label>Usuario:</label> <input type="text" name="uName" placeholder="Escribe el usuario" autocomplete="off" required /><br><br>
                    <label>Contraseña:</label><input type="password" id="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Escribe la contraseña" autocomplete="off" required />
                    <span class="button" type="button">Mostrar</span><br><br>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit-login" value="login"/>
                

            </form>
                <?php echo $out;?>
        </center>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
//Función para visualizar contraseña
document.querySelector('.campo span').addEventListener('click', e => {
    const passwordInput = document.querySelector('#password');
    if (e.target.classList.contains('show')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('show');
            e.target.textContent = 'Ocultar';
            passwordInput.type = 'text';
    } else {
            e.target.classList.add('show');
            e.target.textContent = 'Mostrar';
            passwordInput.type = 'password';
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigue sin funcionar. Este es el código php, es una copia del de arriba.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {
    session_start();
    require ("pages/conn/connection.php");

        $uName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uName']);
        $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass1']);
        $grupo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['grupo']);

        $salted ="********".$pass1."*****";
        $hashed = hash('sha512',$salted);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uName ='$uName' AND pass1 ='$hashed' AND grupo = '$grupo'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("BAD SQL: $query");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row["grupo"] == "admin") {
                $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
                header("location:pages/recibos/menu.php", true, 301);
                //require('pages/session/cookie.php');      
            } elseif ($row["grupo"] == "renta") {
                $_SESSION['login'] = "1";               
                header("location:pages/rentas/rentas.php", true, 301); 
                //require('pages/session/cookie.php');
            } else {
                die("Fail to login. Check user or/and password");
            }
        }
}
```

Si dejo el mysqli_fetch_array con query `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {` recibo el error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in /volume1/web/control/index.php on line 18